# Physically recover heroku postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-s3, wal-e

Heroku makes clear in its [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection) and in its [blog](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/9/26/wal_e_and_continuous_protection_with_heroku_postgres) that it stores postgres database physical backups (that's binary copies of the database cluster files) in S3 using its software called [wal-e](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e).

Does somebody know if there is a way for the final user to access them?

Notice that I'm talking about physical backup, not the logical one provided by [PGBackups plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups). This issue is related with a database in the free plan, without rollbacks, forks nor follows.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote and write most of WAL-E on Heroku's behalf. There is no access to the archives because it is operating system and architecture bit-depth dependent.  On the "Free" and "Hobby" tiers the archives contain a mix of data from multiple tenants, which is relevant to why fork/follow are not supported.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thank you very much for your answer @fdr